# Multiple messages to insert/delete rows in UITableView gets data source out of sync

Tags: iphone, uitableview, datasource, uiswitch

Is there any way to handle the case where you have a UI element in a UITableView, and this controls which rows are shown or hidden in that UITableView and one is to 'double tap' or send multiple messages to the selector such that it 'inserts' and 'deletes' cells before updating the table (and then crashes because the data source is out of sync)?

This issue is present on (at least) iOS 5.0.1 when you go into setting and double tap (or tap quickly a lot of times) 'cellular data' the personal hotspot row gets stuffed, although no exception is thrown.......? This looks like a bug, however pretty innocuous, but still I thought it was good UI fuzz haha!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not technically a bug as it gives us a way to handle an event when someone is sending the message multiple times, the solution is to set the check for and update in a variable and not an object. I wrote an answer here: [Showing and hiding UITableViewCell with UISwitch too fast crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174142/showing-and-hiding-uitableviewcell-with-uiswitch-too-fast-crashes)